# SQL Server 2008 Count in Case statement yielding same result with different parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to count the number of hits for a certain operator as the total for a week, then each day

I can add the declare and select statement for the variables if necessary, but they have the desired effect with a similar sum function, so this seems unnecessary.

I get the same result each day, which is equal to the week in total- not the desired effect. Can anyone shed any light on why the between statements are seemingly being ignored?

```
SELECT HITS.OPPO
, COUNT(CASE WHEN STOP_TIME BETWEEN @StartMinSix   and @TodayEnd      THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS 'COUNT_TOTAL'
, COUNT(CASE WHEN STOP_TIME BETWEEN @TodayDate     and @TodayEnd      THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS 'COUNT_TODAY'
, COUNT(CASE WHEN STOP_TIME BETWEEN @StartMinOne   and @TodayDate     THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS 'COUNT_YESTERDAY'
, COUNT(CASE WHEN STOP_TIME BETWEEN @StartMinTwo   and @StartMinOne   THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS 'COUNT_TODAY_MIN2'
, COUNT(CASE WHEN STOP_TIME BETWEEN @StartMinThree and @StartMinTwo   THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS 'COUNT_TODAY_MIN3'
, COUNT(CASE WHEN STOP_TIME BETWEEN @StartMinFour  and @StartMinThree THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS 'COUNT_TODAY_MIN4'
, COUNT(CASE WHEN STOP_TIME BETWEEN @StartMinFive  and @StartMinFour  THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS 'COUNT_TODAY_MIN5'
, COUNT(CASE WHEN STOP_TIME BETWEEN @StartMinSix   and @StartMinFive  THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS 'COUNT_TODAY_MIN6'

FROM HITS

WHERE HITS.OPPO = @operator
    and STOP_TIME > @StartMinSix
    and ESTIMATED_COST > 0
GROUP BY HITS.OPPO
```

Comment: Try changing count to sum.

Comment: Well played sir- if you put this as an answer I'll accept.  Thanks.

Comment: you are counting how many 0's and 1's you have, if you want to be cryptic, change the 0 to null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need SUM instead of COUNT

```
   SELECT HITS.OPPO
    , SUM(CASE WHEN STOP_TIME BETWEEN @StartMinSix   and @TodayEnd      THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS 'COUNT_TOTAL'
    , SUM(CASE WHEN STOP_TIME BETWEEN @TodayDate     and @TodayEnd      THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS 'COUNT_TODAY'
    , SUM(CASE WHEN STOP_TIME BETWEEN @StartMinOne   and @TodayDate     THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS 'COUNT_YESTERDAY'
    , SUM(CASE WHEN STOP_TIME BETWEEN @StartMinTwo   and @StartMinOne   THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS 'COUNT_TODAY_MIN2'
    , SUM(CASE WHEN STOP_TIME BETWEEN @StartMinThree and @StartMinTwo   THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS 'COUNT_TODAY_MIN3'
    , SUM(CASE WHEN STOP_TIME BETWEEN @StartMinFour  and @StartMinThree THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS 'COUNT_TODAY_MIN4'
    , SUM(CASE WHEN STOP_TIME BETWEEN @StartMinFive  and @StartMinFour  THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS 'COUNT_TODAY_MIN5'
    , SUM(CASE WHEN STOP_TIME BETWEEN @StartMinSix   and @StartMinFive  THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS 'COUNT_TODAY_MIN6'

    FROM HITS

    WHERE HITS.OPPO = @operator
        and STOP_TIME > @StartMinSix
        and ESTIMATED_COST > 0
    GROUP BY HITS.OPPO
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT HITS.OPPO
, COUNT(CASE WHEN STOP_TIME BETWEEN @StartMinSix   and @TodayEnd      THEN 1  ELSE NULL END) AS 'COUNT_TOTAL' ....etc